# Installing airflow in /home/username/.local/bin instead of /usr/local/bin

Tags: installation, airflow

I am trying to install airflow but by default it installs airflow in
/home//.local/bin directory.
I want to install in /usr/local/bin. My PATH env variable includes /usr/local/bin.
Please help me find out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set `airflow home` first

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/user/.local/bin
```

Then install airflow,

```
poetry install airflow
```

Note: I prefer using poetry to manage airflow installation due to cleanliness and maintainability.

Comment: export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/user/.local/bin will install configuration file, log directory etc in "/home/user/.local/bin" folder. My question is when we install airflow, airflow gets installed (airflow file) in "/home/user/.local/bin" folder. But I want to install this file under "/usr/local/bin" folder.